# Oracle problems with dbms_xmlgen package

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dbms-xmlgen

I have a weird problem with `dbms_xmlgen` package in Oracle 10g.

Here's my situation:

Queries using this package usually work as expected, without issues.

I.E.:

```
SQL> select dbms_xmlgen.getXML('select 1 from dual') from dual;
DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT1FRO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <_x0031_>1</_x0031_>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

However, yesterday afternoon, they (the queries using `dbms_xmlgen` package) stopped working at all with the following error:

```
ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [pef.c:pefpargs2()], [30], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [pef.c:pefpargs2()]
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 229
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 175
```

Rebooting Oracle server fixed the issue.

The thing is, we are relying on this feature for a couple of integration features we are about to deploy, and I don't want to have unexpected problems when we're on production environment.

Any ideas/patches/experiences on the same issue?

Here's Oracle version we're using (`select * from v$version`):

```
BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not found anything about that error. You can try to:
Ensure that server process have not been killed in the background by 
checking alert_.log for more info on internal error, and in the trace files referenced there.
Less probable causes:
Check if you have special data like '<' or unicode chars that will be output.
Check your database and client character set.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle "internal error" are internal errors..and as such can only be properly diagnosed by Oracle.

your best option is to contact Oracle support.